Docker push gitlab ci randomly throwing "denied: requested access to the resource is denied"
I use a self-hosted Gitlab registry and repository to store my code and images.
Here is gitlab-ci.yaml part
build-prod:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - cat $PROD_BACKEND_TG_ENV_FILE >> .env
    - docker login ${CI_REGISTRY} --username ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} --password ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
  script:
    - make build-image
    - make push-image
  only:
    - prod
  tags:
    - builder-vm

Whenever a merge request is merged and the pipeline runs it randomly throws an error like below
$ make push-image
docker push git.optochka.com:5050/fmcg/backend-tg:prod
The push refers to repository [git.optochka.com:5050/fmcg/backend-tg]
8d4aa99cfdfc: Preparing
45e1587c781c: Preparing
016b1f09ba3b: Preparing
b1859dd19446: Preparing
4978e78c2de8: Preparing
365ccd918307: Preparing
1bba629c69e9: Preparing
139c1270acf1: Preparing
4693057ce236: Preparing
365ccd918307: Waiting
1bba629c69e9: Waiting
139c1270acf1: Waiting
4693057ce236: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
make: *** [Makefile:10: push-image] Error 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Then I rerun the job and it works. I am not being able to figure out what is happening under the hood
EDIT:
I experienced the same issue on www.gitlab.com too with self hosted runner. I suspect that it is because of using one runner parallel whiling pushing the docker image
EDIT 2: I can confirm it happens when using one Gitlab runner for two pipeline at the same time to push the docker image.

I do not see in your job the DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG environment variable, as mentioned in this thread:

Docker needs to authenticate to GitLab before it can push images to registry. If you are running it in a Pipeline job this is usually done by setting DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG.

See more with the official documentation "Access an image from a private container registry".

There are two approaches that you can take to access a private registry. Both require setting the CI/CD variable DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG with appropriate authentication information.

Per-job: To configure one job to access a private registry, add DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG as a CI/CD variable.
Per-runner: To configure a runner so all its jobs can access a private registry, add DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG as an environment variable in the runner’s configuration.


Simplify your job to just display this environment variable: once its JSON content is confirmed and constant, you can try again pushing to the registry.

Why would I need this? Because it works 90% of the time. It happens randomly for some reason. I will try to put this variable in and wait for the next error to appear. I can not instantly represent the exact error case

@Sherzod I do not know why the authentication information might not be consistently available throughout the entire job. The goal is to test if, when you add consistently a valid DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG, the docker push works 100%, not 90%.

it is happening when I push to the registry at the two pipeline at the same time using one runner. I will try using the different runners to the registry at once. We see how it goes.
